# Airflow - Task status missing in the UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am running Airflow 2.6.0 (CeleryExecutor, Postgres/Redis). I have been running it for the last few month.
Lately, I have observed missing tasks status in the UI:

[image]

This happens across multiple DAGs and at random it seems. The scheduler and worker logs do not show any errors. The webserver logs some time show:

`[2023-08-14T18:30:40.862+0000] {file_task_handler.py:517} ERROR - Could not read served logs`

But these errors pre date this issue (I log to S3 and sometime the S3 API is too slow to load in the UI).
The tasks are running, the UI is just not showing the statuses.

I ran "airflow db clean ..." to try and cleanup the records in the metadata store, but the problem persists.

I suspect a problem with the DB but I am not sure where to go from here. I don't want to reset the database. I did try to restart the webserver but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this by upgrading to 2.6.3, which has a [bugfix for deleting task instances from the UI](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/32684).

Comment: I just upgraded to 2.6.3 today but it was a shot in the dark, I missed the bugfix you mention. Thanks, I will be testing in the next few days.